# Sorting an NSArray result is wiered

Tags: ios, objective-c, sorting, nsarray

How do you sort NSArray, I am trying this way but getting wiered result.

This is the code i am using.

```
- (void)fetchedData:(NSData *)responseData
{
    NSLog(@"Key to sort = %@",keyToSort);
    NSError* error;
    NSDictionary *mainDic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
    NSArray *mainArr = [mainDic objectForKey:@"data"];
    // Sortion
    NSSortDescriptor *valueDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:keyToSort ascending:YES];
    NSArray *descriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:valueDescriptor];
    NSArray *sortedArray = [mainArr sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:descriptors];

    for (int i = 0; i < [sortedArray count]; i++)
    {
        NSDictionary *subDic = [sortedArray objectAtIndex:i];
        [rankNumber addObject:[subDic valueForKey:keyToSort]]; // rankNumber is an Array
    }
}
```

The OutPut is

```
0
1
10
11
12
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

Any Idea or Suggestion, Please help to solve this issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following line:

```
NSSortDescriptor *valueDescriptor =  [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"statusIdNo" ascending:YES selector:@selector(localizedStandardCompare:)];
```

instead of

```
NSSortDescriptor *valueDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:keyToSort ascending:YES];
```

Comment: I know, that's SO's rule. just do it when you can :)